# Board with MCU with USB controller + USB connector; how can I have two USB ports?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I have a board with an MCU which has a USB controller + USB connector. I need 2 usb ports. How can I accomplish that with minimal or without any modifications to the board? Something like a simple USB hub for PCs, etc. Both of the USBs will be used for writing/reading to/from FLASH.

The board also has I2C, and two GPIOs. The MCU is an MKL25z128.

Comment: Hosting USB flash on this may not be a great idea, though since it's external anyway you can use an off the shelf hub.  Or consider an SD card in place of one device, using dedicates SPI.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve? Will both USB ports act as USB device (as opposed to USB host)? Will they implement a mass storage device? Do they provide access to the same or to separate flash data? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB hub chip to provide two physical USB ports.

Comment: There are also MCUs with more than one USB controller. Or you could use a second (possibly simpler) MCU.